# How to get group name of highlighting under cursor in vim?

Tags: vim

I usually customize existing `colorscheme` to meet my needs.

If I could get the syntax group name under cursor, it would help me a lot, just like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) but in Vim. I'd like to know how to do it.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There is this function that was floating around the web when I was doing the same thing:

```
function! SynStack()
  if !exists("*synstack")
    return
  endif
  echo map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")')
endfunc
```

Comment: If you are here because you're trying to diagnose lots of red highlighting, that's [due to spellcheck](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28647994/annoying-red-highlighting-of-random-words-in-vim) and SynStack() doesn't seem to detect that for some reason.

Answer (score 35):

The following function will output both the name of the syntax group, and the translated syntax group of the character the cursor is on:

```
function! SynGroup()
    let l:s = synID(line('.'), col('.'), 1)
    echo synIDattr(l:s, 'name') . ' -> ' . synIDattr(synIDtrans(l:s), 'name')
endfun
```

To make this more convenient it can be wrapped in a custom command or key binding.

How this works:

- `line('.')` and `col('.')` return the current position
- `synID(...)` returns a numeric syntax ID
- `synIDtrans(l:s)` translates the numeric syntax id `l:s` by following highlight links
- `synIDattr(l:s, 'name')` returns the name corresponding to the numeric syntax ID

This will echo something like:

```
vimMapModKey -> Special
```

Comment: I find this considerably better than the accepted answer because it often saves me following through one or more 'links to' highlight entries when trying to figure out what I am looking to change.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a mapping that will show the hierarchy of the synstack() and also show the highlight links. press gm to use it.

```
function! SynStack ()
    for i1 in synstack(line("."), col("."))
        let i2 = synIDtrans(i1)
        let n1 = synIDattr(i1, "name")
        let n2 = synIDattr(i2, "name")
        echo n1 "->" n2
    endfor
endfunction
map gm :call SynStack()<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
" diagnostics {{{
if has('balloon_eval')
    nnoremap <F12>           : setl beval!<CR>
    set bexpr=InspectSynHL()
endif
fun! InspectSynHL()
    let l:synNames = []
    let l:idx = 0
    for id in synstack(v:beval_lnum, v:beval_col)
        call add(l:synNames, printf('%s%s', repeat(' ', idx), synIDattr(id, 'name')))
        let l:idx+=1
    endfor
    return join(l:synNames, "\n")
endfun
"}}}
```