# Annoying, red highlighting of random words in vim

Tags: vim

I have this problem identifying the reason word get this annoying red background in my vim:

[image]

Do you happen to know why vim highlights random words throughout documents that I open and how I can turn this off?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You have the spell check switched on. Switch it off using

```
:set nospell
```

(source: http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/357267-using-spell-checking-in-vim)

Comment: Thank you for this answer! My recommendation is to add this to your ~/.vimrc file; the default on my Mac had spellcheck turned on.

Comment: Thanks kindly! If you want to avoid this in an apache .conf file like I did, you can add it to the end, like "# vim: nospell".

Comment: Or, you could [add words to spelling dictionary](https://superuser.com/questions/133208/how-to-make-vim-spellcheck-remember-a-new-word).

Comment: I have to do `set nospell`, every time that *red* happens! Setting this in the `.vimrc` does not work for me! Why, is that?

Comment: @quanta Are you using "vi" or "vim"? Please, try `vim <file>`.

Answer (score 8):

Disabling highlighting is not always something you really want to do. Instead, you can change the style of your error, so they become more friendly. Put this after setting any style:

```
" Any other stuff like setting colorscheme
" colorscheme distinguished

" Change style of highlighting
 hi clear SpellBad
 hi SpellBad cterm=underline
```

As a result, your errors will be underlined in not-annoying way.

Comment: This is great but confuses the links. Would like to know other workarounds.

Answer (score 6):

This has relation to the syntax highlighting the fas way to get rid of it is turn the syntax highlighting off by using the following command:

```
:syntax off
```

Comment: I'd rather keep syntax formatting for easier editing.

Comment: This answer works for me. My vim was highlighting a `.conf` file based on it's own interpretation of the syntax (and it is up to the individual reader to decide whether `:syntax off` is right for them. -(-1))

Comment: `:syntax off` followed by `:syntax on` seems to do it for me. Not a concrete solution but it's something

Answer (score 1):

In my case I went in a few circles thinking it was a cached search (`:set noh`, `:set nohlsearch` etc were no avail) but actually it was my mistake and I forgot that my new .vimrc was using syntax highlighting and it was a syntax error the red highlight was flagging. Fixing these solved the issue, but if that's not an option `:syntax off` is your go-to.