# vim: search for a colored string in the file

Tags: vim

When I open a build result file, some keywords are in different colors. Example some occurrence of `SUCCESS` is in green color and some occurrence of `FAILURE` in red color. How can I search only `FAILURE` in `red` font?

Answer (score 1):

You have to be aware that your request is not about *searching in a text file*, because a text file has no colors in it; what gives it colors is the editor, in this case Vim, via some color scheme and rules to detect what is the syntactical role of each part of the text.

So one way to go about it, is just to

- search the next word, ***for instance*** via the regex `\w\+`,
- check what is the color group associated with the word under the cursor,
- stop the search if the the group is the one we are looking for, otherwise repeat the procedure.

Here's a very basic attempt to search for next string in a `*.vim` file:

```
" Function that gets the highlight group for the word under the cursor
" I've adapted it from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9464929/5825294
nmap <C-S-P> :echo <SID>SynStack()<CR>
function! <SID>SynStack()
    if !exists("*synstack")
        return
    endif
    return map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")')
endfunc

" Function that implements the logic in the bullet point list
nmap gn :call <SID>SearchNextVimString()<CR>
function! <SID>SearchNextVimString()
  call search('\w\+')
  while match(SynStack(), 'vimString') == -1
    call search('\w\+')
  endwhile
endfunction
```

What you would have to do in order to adapt it to your case is:

- open your file, go to one `FAILURE` word which is highlighted in red,
- hit <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-P</kbd> and take note of the rightmost group,
- change `vimString` in my example with that group (and maybe also the name of the function `SearchNextVimString` to something more appropariate,
- try it out.

Then, if you're not happy with it, I think you'll have to change the regex `\w\+` to something more appropriate. At least.

Answer (score 0):

The color is defined by syntax group, which is possibly defined by a pattern. If you can find it, you can use it as the search pattern directly.

- Move the cursor onto the word, like `FAILURE`.
- Run the below command to get the topmost syntax group `<group-name>`

  ```
  echo map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")')[0]
  ```
- Find the location where it's defined

  ```
  verb highlight <group-name>
  ```