# How Can I Check if the Current Line is Commented in Vim Script

Tags: vim, comments, vim-plugin

I am writing a Vim plugin and I want to detect if the current line is commented.
If the line is not commented, I want it to do  something.
Pseudo-code:

```
if !commented
    do something
endif
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464844/how-to-get-group-name-of-highlighting-under-cursor-in-vim

Comment: That Stack Overflow link you sent me isn't helpful because it does not work when putting it in a Vim script file. It only works when running it in command mode.

Comment: @Amarakon That link gives the solution to your problem and can be used in your vim script file.

Comment: How would I implement it in my function? I tried all of the solutions, and they didn't work in the function. I can do this `echo map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")')`, and that works in command mode, but it doesn't work when I try to do it in a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below.

> ```
> " Check if current line is commented. 
> " Comment starts with --
> let commented = ! match(getline('.'), ' *--.*')
> ```

`getline('.')` will get current line's content.
`match` will compare the line with the pattern.
When current line is start with `--`, match result is 0.
If patter is found in the middle of line, match result is positive number.
If patter is not found, match result is -1.
After logic not, you will get commented flag.

Comment: Please add some context and explanation for future readers.